# disappearing highstock series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am stuck on a series disappearance issue on highstock v1.3.10.
I have tried setting ignoreHiddenSeries to false, adjusting minRange and min/maxPadding but adjusting range still wipes off one of my series (called raffData, myChart.series[3])

Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

**Issue reproduction steps:**

1. change series type to stepline.
2. select 2yr in range selector
3. Raff channels disappear when in a widescreen resolution (desktop).

They will reappear when adjusting the xAxis range, when candle or ohlc is re-selected, or when the browser width is minimized (with chart.reflow set to true).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danb201268326/CXtGs/)

[fullscreen result](http://jsfiddle.net/danb201268326/CXtGs/embedded/result/)

```
myChart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart : {
        panning: false,
        ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
        renderTo : 'container',
        alignTicks: false,
        marginLeft : 25
    },

    plotOptions : {
        line : {
            lineWidth : 0.7
        },
        series : {animation : true}
    },

    rangeSelector : {
        inputDateFormat: '%e %b, %Y',
        inputEditDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
        //selected : 1,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 6,
            text: '6m'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 2,
            text: '2y'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 3,
            text: '3y'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 5,
            text: '5y'
        },  {
            type: 'year',
            count: 10,
            text: '10y'
        },  {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }]
    },

    title : {
        text : getTick
    },

    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals : 2
    },

    navigator : {
        enabled : true
    },          

    yAxis : [{                      
        gridLineWidth : 0.8,
        height : 410
    }],

    series : [{
        type : series_type, // ohlc, candlestick, spline...
        step : true,
        name : getTick,
        data : data,
        lineWidth : 1,
        dataGrouping : {
            enabled : false,
            units : [[
            'week',
                [1]
            ], [
                'month', 
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ],[
                'year',
                null
            ]]
        }

    },
    {
        type: 'spline',
        name : 'linReg',
        data : lrData,
        enableMouseTracking : true,
        color : '#F0F0F0',
        dashStyle : 'Dash',
        lineWidth : 1
    },
    {
        type: 'areasplinerange',
        name : 'RaffChannel',
        data : raffData,
        enableMouseTracking : false,
        color : '#839bfc',
        dashStyle : 'Dash',
        fillOpacity : 0.2,
        lineWidth : 1,
        yAxis : 0
    }] //end series
}); //ends chart
```

Comment: Could you simplify a little your example? It's 700lines of code..

Comment: thanks for responding Pawel. I have stripped back the script but can only get down to under 400 lines to produce this issue.
Sorry for late response. Dan

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I overcame the issue by loading an additional hidden series that contains just date and the close price.

So for line, spline or area types I simply hide the OHLC series and show the close-only series using setVisible *without* redraw. Referring to the series by myChart.get(id) is a reliable way of pointing to the correct series.